# Cross model queries in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

F.e. I have three models:

ModelA, 
ModelB, 
ModelC

ModelA has an array with ids of instances of ModelB. ModelB has an array with ids of instances of ModelC.

How can I query all instances of ModelC that are members of all instances of ModelB that are members of instance of ModelA?

```
ModelA
   ∟ [
      ModelB
        ∟ [ModelC, ModelC, ModelC]
      ModelB
        ∟ [ModelC, ModelC, ModelC, ModelC]
      ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Are `ModelB` and `ModelC` embedded documents? Or are they references? Assuming they are references, then you will have to first load all `ModelA` instances and then load all `ModelB` instances and so on. Unfortunetly MongoDB does not support joins, so there is nothing else you can do ( well, you can always try running map/reduce ). It looks like SQL database might be a better choice for whatever you are trying to do.